# Vite Library Mode Build Different between Windows and Linux

Tags: node-modules, vite

This is a crosspost from my [github discussion](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/9826), but I wanted to see if anyone has any thoughts here.

I'm using vite for an npm package that's in "library mode."  I have 2 files:

**utilities.ts**

```
export function thisGetsRemovedInBundle() {
  console.log('This should be in the bundle!');
}

export function thisIsUsed() {
  console.log('Used!');
  return 1;
}
```

**components/index.ts**

```
import { thisIsUsed } from '../utilities';

export default {
  Hello: thisIsUsed(),
};
```

**vite.config.ts**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: 'components/index.ts',
      formats: ['es'],
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['vue'],
      input: {
        index: 'components/index.ts',
        utilities: 'utilities.ts',
      },
      output: {
        dir: 'dist',
        format: 'es',
        entryFileNames: '[name].js',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

When I build this on a Windows 10 machine, it produces the following in `index.js`:

```
function thisIsUsed() {
  console.log("Used!");
  return 1;
}
var index = {
  Hello: thisIsUsed()
};
export { index as default };
```

On Ubuntu, it produces this:

```
import { thisIsUsed } from "./utilities.js";
var index = {
  Hello: thisIsUsed()
};
export { index as default };
```

Notice in the Windows build, it doesn't import the function but rather adds it as if it's part of `index.js`.  I would expect it to be like the latter because in the Windows bundle, it has duplicated code (both files have a copy of `thisIsUsed`).

Is there some fundamental `npm` or `node` magic that I'm missing between these builds?  If so, how do I solve this issue so my build always looks like the Ubuntu build (without having to use a Linux machine or Unix shell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reporting a bug [here](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/9939), and while it appears valid, it can be fixed easily by using `path.resolve` and `__dirname` when defining the path to the input files.  e.g. in the `vite.config.ts` above, it should be:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: 'components/index.ts',
      formats: ['es'],
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['vue'],
      input: {
        index: path.resolve(__dirname, 'components/index.ts'),
        utilities: path.resolve(__dirname, 'utilities.ts'),
      },
      output: {
        dir: 'dist',
        format: 'es',
        entryFileNames: '[name].js',
      },
    },
  },
});
```